# Split row based on result of divide operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have data shipment and multiply of 1 basket, Before :

```
Pack ID Brand   Part    Ship Qty    Qty per Basket  divideval   mod Batch
4       Brand A Part P  145         50              2           45  OB
4       Brand A Part P  125         50              2           25  OB2
```

I need to multiple the data based on ship qty / qty per basket, After :

```
Pack ID Brand   Part    Ship Qty    Batch
4       Brand A Part P  50          OB
4       Brand A Part P  50          OB
4       Brand A Part P  45          OB
4       Brand A Part P  50          OB2
4       Brand A Part P  50          OB2
4       Brand A Part P  25          OB2
```

How to make it using SQL Server?

Comment: It's possible with a recursive query if you pass the remaining parts line after line until you match the ship size. Otherwise, procstocks. Could you detail what each value correspond to? It's not obvious in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already calculated the `Qty per Basket`, it makes thing a little bit simpler.

The solution use a number / tally table or recursive cte to generate one.

The following query uses a number table

```
select  t.PackID, t.Brand, t.Part, 
        case when n = 1 and [mod] <> 0 then [mod] else t.QtyperBasket end as ShipQty, 
        t.Batch
from    yourtable t
        cross join numbers n
where   n.n >= 1
and     n.n <= t.divideval + case when [mod] > 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: what is number table?? i don't understand... and [mod] is wrong also... i used SS 2017 right now

Comment: number or tally table are just a table with single column that contains numbers that starts from 0 or 1 up to your requirement. Just do a search and you will find lots of reference to that

Comment: what do you mean by `and [mod] is wrong also` ? Please elaborate

Comment: `The SQL Server Numbers Table, Explained` https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/